# Recording audio issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, audio, audio-recording

I am developing an app for recording video and audio but it seems that the audio is not working. sometimes it works but most of the time its not.

Here is my code

```
self.captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

[self.captureSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset352x288];

AVCaptureDevice *videoDevice = [self frontCamera];
AVCaptureDevice *audioDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];

self.videoInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:videoDevice error:nil];
self.audioInput = [[AVCaptureDeviceInput alloc] initWithDevice:audioDevice error:nil];

self.stillImageOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
NSDictionary *stillImageOutputSettings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                          AVVideoCodecJPEG, AVVideoCodecKey, nil];
[self.stillImageOutput setOutputSettings:stillImageOutputSettings];

self.movieOutput = [[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput alloc] init];

// Setup capture session for taking pictures
[self.captureSession addInput:self.videoInput];
[self.captureSession addInput:self.audioInput];
[self.captureSession addOutput:self.stillImageOutput];
[self.captureSession addOutput:self.movieOutput];
```